# how to add webview in listview in android

Tags: android

Hi can anybody tell how to add webview in list view in android

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to archive by doing that? You can use something like list_item.xml to create a layout for a single item of ListView. But the content of your items is provided by an adapter, which provides data fast. To load web content may take time, consider that your list should enable fluent scrolling.